# Django Models: How to setup these DB constraints on the fields?

Tags: django-models

Suppose I have the following Model:

```
class myClassObj(models.Model):
    flag1 = models.NullBooleanField() 
    flag2 = models.BooleanField()
```

Now also suppose I want the Database to enforce the following constraint:

```
flag1 should be None if and only if flag2 is false
```

How can I write the constraints in this model so that this condition is checked any time a myClassObj is created or edited? I see some interesting information [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/django-check-constraints/wiki/Features). But I don't see how to specify an "iff" constraint as I described above.

Comment: you can write a `pre_save()` signal that can achieve this for you

Answer (score 0):

The Django documentation recommends doing custom validation where access to multiple fields is required by overriding `Model.clean()`.

This example from the documentation show how it's possible to validate that a news article still in the "draft" phase does not have a publication date.

```
def clean(self):
    import datetime
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    # Don't allow draft entries to have a pub_date.
    if self.status == 'draft' and self.pub_date is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Draft entries may not have a publication date.')
    # Set the pub_date for published items if it hasn't been set already.
    if self.status == 'published' and self.pub_date is None:
        self.pub_date = datetime.date.today()
```

For more detailed information, see the full reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

To have this called every time you save the object you'll also need to override the save method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods.

Another useful reference for other use cases if you only need to validate a single field is writing custom validators: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. clean() has to be called manually. Right? How can I make this happen automatically during the save()?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to override save to call the the clean method before calling save from the superclass: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods